# How can I find out what happened in my question and to another user?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday night I asked [a question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120748/what-should-you-do-if-you-caught-ransomware-mid-operation). A [user](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/104162/brent-kirkpatrick) felt that part of my question was off-topic. We engaged in a discussion of maybe 10 comments. I took his opinion into consideration, and thus edited my question a little bit. (But perhaps not as much as he would have liked me to.) I then went to bed.

I wake up to find that the activity on the question has been above average, with several answers and comments.

However, the user I had the discussion with is now temporarily suspended, and all his comments are deleted. Most of my own comments in response to him are deleted too.

Although the user was somewhat zealous, it surprises me a little bit that he got suspended. And I'm somewhat curious as to whether he did more after I went to sleep, and what the basis for his suspension was. His comments before I went to sleep were, although maybe a bit opinionated, not that bad.

How can I find out what happened while I was sleeping? As I am very new to this site I feel that this would be useful to know, in terms of learning about the etiquette and rules here, etc.

Comment: I realize this is 2 weeks old, but without clicking the link, I took a wild guess based on your description, and yup same guy. lol. Over 50% of his questions are closed as [off topic] and he has a negative overall question score, yet he regularly harranges new users over his misguided opinions of what's acceptable on this site. He's suspended for a reason: we're fed up with it.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Haha, interesting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suspensions tend to be for a number of things which add up to that result. His activity on your question was effectively a final straw. He had been warned about this behaviour and suspended for it previously.

The rules which govern Stack Exchange sites are listed out under [about] and [help] so that would be a good place to start.

Also, if you do overstep the mark, the community will initially provide hints and guidance before flagging for moderators to pitch in - we typically are the escalation step when the community needs something done.

Comment: So he didn't continue arguing with other people after I left? It was all based on his interaction with me? Given previous warnings?

Comment: No - it wasn't just with you.

Comment: Oh... I wish I would have been awake to observe the show... But  I guess it's too late to see the deleted comments now? :)

Comment: No exciting drama, trust me.

Comment: Never underestimate the force of human curiosity :)

Comment: That's exactly why we aren't allowed to see what leads to the suspensions, because we're curious about something we don't actually need to know until we get to Rory level.

Comment: Almost exactly the same thing happened again today. A user (different guy, though) was unnecessarily arguing with me over the validity of my questions. I flagged his comments as "not constructive." I came back a few hours later to find all comments (both his and mine) deleted. I guess that guy just liked to argue? When mods delete comments like this, is the offending user notified?

Comment: These were the questions: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120902/would-limiting-write-access-to-a-backup-directory-help-protect-it-from-ransomwar http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121080/do-the-most-common-ransomware-programs-delete-the-original-files-as-they-go-or?noredirect=1#comment221557_121080

Comment: Comments are supposed to be temporary. Stack exchange is for questions and answers, and comments are too request clarity, so generally comments that have served their purpose or don't add anything just get deleted. This is normal

Comment: @RoryAlsop Alright, thanks. Didn't see your comment until now.